# Bundle static/shared libraries in generated .aar

Tags: android, cmake, java-native-interface

I'm working with Android Studio to generate `.aar` Android modules. It allows me to expose Java classes and methods to call them in other projects.

One of these methods is a C++ method defined in a static library and called from Java through the JNI.

When importing the `.aar` and trying to call such a method, I'm greeted with an "undefined reference". Decompressing the `.aar` and searching through it shows me that it doesn't contain any traces of my static/shared libraries generated through Android Studio with Cmake.

How can I remedy this?

Content of CMakeLists.txt generating the libraries:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS "--whole-archive")

# Find the android-log library for debug purposes
find_library(log-lib log)

# Set directory variables
set(LIBS_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs)
set(SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

# Compiles the static transaction library from sources
add_library(code-logic
            STATIC
            ${SRC_DIR}/src/CustomAPI.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/src/ParameterAPI.cpp )
include_directories(${SRC_DIR}/inc/)

# Compiled native-lib from native cpp source code
add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp)
# Link it with android-log and transaction-logic
target_link_libraries(native-lib
                      code-logic
                      log       )
```

I can see that the libraries are indeed generated in `ProjectDirectory/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/${ARCH}/libs/${ARCH}/lib.so`, but they don't appear in the `intermediates/` folder or anywhere in the produced `.aar`.

Comment: To build and bundle a shared library into the aar fila (in limmodule/build/outputs/aar) it's enough to run gradle **bundleRelease** task (or **bundleDebug** if you want). This does not work for static lib, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look tomorrow!

Comment: @AlexCohn: I just tried it, but the generated `.aar` doesn't contain the libraries for some reason, even though they are generating during the build process. I really can't explain it... I guess I'll stick to my manual building script solution

Comment: maybe you should not override `LIBS_DIR`?

Comment: Wait, is this a reserved Android variable?

Comment: No, and in my experiment it had no effect. But why do you set it, how is it used? BTW, in your script **SRC_DIR** is not necessary, too. Neither is `find_library` for log.

Comment: I'm actually linking my lib against log. Do you mean that the log symbol already exists because android pre-defines it? I just followed the official documentation on this one. In the code I put, you're right that LIBS_DIR isn't used but in my actual project I use it, forgot to remove it here

Comment: Yes, NDK comes with the **build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake** script that defined **log** and many other niceties.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any "built-in" solution, so I added a script to my build process, called at the very end. It "unzips" the `.aar` file, edits it by adding the static/shared libraries compiled by Android Studio, then "re-zips" it into an `.aar` file. Here is the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env /bin/bash

OUT_DIR=`pwd`
LIB_DIR="${OUT_DIR}/tmp/libs"
JNI_DIR="${OUT_DIR}/tmp/jni"
BASE_DIR="${OUT_DIR}/.."
PROJ_NAME="PROJECT_NAME_BASE_DIRECTORY"
LIB_NAME="LIB_NAME.aar"
BUILD_DIR="${BASE_DIR}/${PROJ_NAME}/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release"

rm -rf ./tmp/ && mkdir ./tmp/
unzip ${LIB_NAME} -d ./tmp/

(
  cd "${BUILD_DIR}" \
  && for f in `find . -name "*\.a"`
  do
      mkdir -p "${JNI_DIR}/"$(basename $(dirname "${f}"));
      cp "${f}" "${JNI_DIR}"/$(basename $(dirname "${f}"));
  done \
  && for f in `find . -name "*\.so"`
  do
      mkdir -p "${JNI_DIR}/"$(basename $(dirname "${f}"));
      cp "${f}" "${JNI_DIR}"/$(basename $(dirname "${f}"));
  done
)

rm -f ${LIB_NAME}.aar
jar cvf ${LIB_NAME}.aar -C ./tmp/ .
rm -rf ./tmp/
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the libs dir in build.gradle

```
   android {
   ...
     main {
      jniLibs.srcDirs = [ 'jni/libs', 'externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/${ARCH}/libs/${ARCH}' ] // Where generated .so files are placed.
       ...
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: I've added this to `build.gradle`, but I don't think it's doing any difference. Generating the `.aar` with and without both gives me files of the exact same size...

Comment: I also put `jni.srcDirs = []` in the same section, as we don't build with the ndk but from a bash script

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I just did, a bash script that unzips the .aar, adds the libraries, and zips it back... I think I'll stick to that solution for now

Comment: Okay so I'm putting my `.so` and `.a` inside the `libs/` folder of the `.aar` file, but when I generate an `.apk` from another project using the previously mentioned `.aar`, it doesn't contain any trace of the libraries. Do you have any idea why? :/

Comment: Ah, turns out I had to put my libs in the `jni/` folder, and not in the `lib/` folder... Now I'm getting a SIGSEGV, it's all good :)